# Couchbase full-text search and compound keys

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, couchbase, couchbase-view

I have the following data in Couchbase:

Document `06001`:

```js
{
  "type": "box",
  "name": "lxpag",
  "number": "06001",
  "materials": [
    {
      "type": "material",
      "number": "070006",
      "name": "hosepipe"
    },
    {
      "type": "material",
      "number": "080006",
      "name": "Philips screw 4mm"
    },
}
```

Document `12345`:

```js
{
  "type": "material",
  "number": "12345",
  "name": "Another screw"
}
```

Now I want to be able to query by type and name or number: for a given query type only the documents with the respective type property shall be returned. Furthermore, a second query string specifies which kinds of materials should be searched for. If a material's id or name *contains* (not starts with) the search term, it shall be included. If one of the materials inside a box matches the term accordingly, the whole box shall be included.

What I have come up with is:

```js
function (doc, meta) {
  if (doc.type === 'box' && Array.isArray(doc.materials))  {
    var queryString = "";
    for (i = 0; i < doc.materials.length; ++i) {
      var material = doc.materials[i];
      if (material.name && material.number) {
        queryString += " " + material.name + " " + material.number;
      }
    }
    emit([doc.type, queryString], doc);
  } else if (doc.type === 'material') {
    var queryString = doc.name + " " + doc.number;
    emit([doc.type, queryString], doc);
  }
}
```

I see that this view might not be fit for substring searches (Do I need ElasticSearch for this?). Nevertheless, when I use the following query parameters:

```js
startKey=["box","pag"]&endKey=["box\u02ad","pag\u02ad"]
```

...not only do I get the box but also all other documents that are returned by the view. Thus, with these keys, nothing is filtered. On the other hand, searching by `key` works.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way of doing substring search with view keys. Your options are either integrating with ElasticSearch, or using N1QL, which lets you do wildcard string matches: "SELECT * FROM bucket WHERE type = 'material' and name LIKE '%screw%'"

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the flaw in the queries: the parameters must be written in lowercase, otherwise they are not recognized by Couchbase and ignored (it would be really helpful if I got an error message here instead of the usual result list...). So instead, I have to query with

```js
startKey=["box","pag"]&endKey=["box\u02ad","pag\u02ad"]
```

What I have not precisely found out so far is how to manage the substring search. Since `pag` is a substring of `lxpag` above query would not return any results. Any ideas no this matter?